debug.exe from DOS 6.22 errored on assembling mov ax, imm16 with the `a` command; works in Win 2000
The details of my problem
Enviroment: I was using MS-DOS 6.22 virtual machine in VirtualBox.
Task: With the help of the built-in debug.exe program which lives in C:\DOS\DEBUG.EXE , I wanted to write some instructions into the memory. The detailed progress is as the screenshot shown below:

And below is a text version of the screenshot I wrote manually:
C:\>debug
-a 1000:0
1000:0000 mov ax,ffff
1000:0003 mov ds,ax
1000:0005 mov ax,2200
              ^error
1000:0006 
-u 1000:0 6
1000:0000 b8ffff  mov ax,ffff
1000:0003 8ed8    mov ds,ax
1000:0005 a5      movsw
1000:0006 42      inc dx
-q

It is also confusing to note that the error instruction is turned to movsw in the same memory address.
What I did
I was trying to use the a command in debug.exe to write these commands into memory:
mov ax,ffff
mov ds,ax

mov ax,2200
mov ss,ax

mov sp,0100

mov ax,[0]
mov bx,[2]

push ax
push bx

pop ax
pop bx

Later, I planned to use other commands to execute the instructions and observe the system's behaviors with the aim of learning Assembly.
However, I was stuck at the step of entering the mov ax,2200 instruction, where the program indicated an error at the a. I have no idea why this is happening.
It worked in the Windows2000 Virtual machine!
I installed a new Windows2000 Virtual machine in VirtualBox and did the same thing in the cmd (enter debug.exe and use a to insert instructions). And it worked! So the problem might be related to the MS-DOS 6.22 virtual machine I used?
What is expected
But still, I'm curious about what might have gone wrong in MS-DOS 6.22 , as this situation seems quite unusual to me. Could it be related to debug.exe ? Or are there specific rules for setting up instructions in memory that I may not be aware of?

Professional developers tend to focus on products that are still fully supported by the vendors. But both MS DOS and Windows 2000 reached end of life more than a decade ago.

@LexLi: This site is not just for professionals; amateur hobbyist questions are on topic, too.  If you don't want to see questions about obsolete stuff, don't follow the [dos][x86-16] tags, or actively ignore them.  The question is on-topic here and the OP provided what looks like a solid [mcve], even getting the code-formatting right for a text version of the image.  Upvoted just for being well asked, even though I couldn't care less about what's probably a bug in DOS debug.exe.  Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

This would also be on-topic on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/, and might be of more interest to more readers there, since part of that site's focus is obsolete commercial software like DOS.  IDK why people still use debug.exe when much better assemblers like NASM exist.  It doesn't even support labels; it's insane.  Use a debugger for debugging only, or stuff like modifying one instruction in-place while debugging instead of edit/rebuild/restart the program.  There are DOS debuggers other than debug.exe, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86-16/info

Did you install your VM from some standard image that others could replicate, or in some manual way?

@rcgldr: Thanks, but I was actually asking OP what they were using.

Try assembling in the allocated debuggee process block ie a 100 (an offset only, and >= 100h) rather than a 1000:0. Presumably you're overwriting memory that is already in use differently and this different use causes the error. It doesn't happen on some versions because the memory layout of kernel and Debug itself differs.

If you want to run your code without a DOS running, you could run bootloadable lDebug in a VM. This will install the debugger at the top of the Low Memory Area and leave everything from 00600h up to the debugger free for you to use. (Exact limit can be read from word [0:413h] or interrupt 12h, which boot mode lDebug changes to allocate space to itself.) If you really find a bug in MS-DOS Debug then you could try to reproduce it with my fork, MSDebug (of MS-DOS v2), in which I could then fix the bug.

@rcgldr Why not wait until they've tried a 100 instead of a 1000:0 and see if that fixes it? I cannot reproduce an error with a 100 while writing to 1000h:0 could certainly interfere with the DOS or debugger.

For the OP. the date I have for DEBUG.EXE is 05-31-94, time is 7:22 AM.

@rcgldr You will notice I specified a 1000:0 without the H. Only in the running text that wasn't a command did I write it with the H. If you can identify a bug in MS-DOS Debug I'd be very interested in how to reproduce it. If the address 10000h (indeed that's 64 KiB) isn't a problem then identify what is the problem. To OP: In the debugger that has the problem, try starting it and enter as the very first command r and tell us whether the cs, ds, es, ss value is above 1000 (indicating a segment base of 10000h = 64 KiB). If it is then my overwriting hypothesis seems more likely.

@ecm: You were right: see my answer.  So it's not a DEBUG bug.  Presumably it appeared to work with other versions because address 1000:0 happened not to be in use, or didn't contain anything that was needed for this test case to run correctly.

@James: Read Nate's answer posted 15 minutes before your comment; those would both be assembled as movsw after overwriting the assembler's table of mnemonics at 1000:0, same as before.

@NateEldredge - I deleted my prior comments, I'll delete this one later.

To avoid the issue as answered by @NateEldredge -, when running debug, don't specify the segment, just use a 100, which will default to the first available segment address.

@PeterCordes: Thank you for your advice! I used debug.exe because I was following the labs in an assembly language book that recommended it. However, I’ll look into other options and give them a try, as I’ve found that debug.exe is not very effective.

Unless there's some particular reason you want to learn about retro DOS stuff, I'd recommend learning 32-bit assembly under Linux (or *BSD) or Windows, whichever you have easy access to, and preferably one where you already know some low-level stuff like Linux system calls and strace or Windows WinAPI.  Or 64-bit under any OS.  You can learn about segmentation and extra complications later.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for some links to tutorials and the free book Programming from the Ground Up which is for i386 Linux and is pretty good.

(Or if you're interested in AArch64 or RISC-V, learn those first, they're nicely designed ISAs.)

@PeterCordes: I have learned quite a bit about RISC-V some time ago, and its design is indeed nice and clean. My experience with DOS has primarily been as a tool for studying x86-16 during my microcomputer class. As a result, I won't delve too deeply into the DOS aspect. I will read the book Programming from the Ground Up someday, as I do prefer the Linux stuff. Thanks again for your recommendations!

Oh, if you need to learn DOS and x86-16 crap for a class, then so be it.  Hopefully they don't get too deep into DOS and BIOS APIs, and instead just focus on x86-16 as an ISA they happen to be using to teach general assembly concepts.  One interesting thing about DOS and/or bootloaders on a PC-compatible is that you can access the hardware directly; no OS gets in your way and even modern hardware still has compat modes or SMM emulation for the ancient hardware addresses and IO ports, so e.g. you can mov [es:bx], ax to store 2 bytes to VGA video memory, assuming ES:BX points there.

You seem to have chosen the address 1000:0 arbitrarily, but it doesn't belong to you, and you don't know what it might be used for.  In fact, in this instance, it happens to contain some of DEBUG's own internal data, and so overwriting it causes its assembler to misbehave.
DOS is not a multitasking operating system and has no memory protection.  Everything shares the same memory space, including the code you are trying to assemble, DEBUG.COM itself, and the DOS kernel.  So if you overwrite arbitrary memory, you may very well break something other than your own code.
Don't do that. If you just use a without giving an address, you'll assemble into memory that's set aside for you, and can safely be written.

What happens specifically is the following.  We can follow along in DEBUG's source code.
(The source code is for MS-DOS 4.0 rather than 6.22, but as I stepped through the execution in 6.22 using Bochs, the disassembly of the relevant parts matches the 4.0 source, so it evidently hadn't changed.  The misbehavior was actually slightly different in my test than in yours, likely because DEBUG got loaded at a different address, but there's enough info in your question to infer what must have happened for you.)
The bytes you overwrote provide a hint: 43 58 5A 00 4A 4E 42 is "CXZ\0JNB".  We are inside DEBUG's list of mnemonic strings, specifically here; they are separated by null bytes.
Your first instruction MOV AX, FFFF is three bytes long, so it overwrites CXZ.  That doesn't cause any tangible harm because you aren't attempting to assemble any JCXZ instructions.
Your second instruction MOV DS, AX, however, overwrites the null byte at 1000:3, which was the separator between JCXZ and JNB.  Now the damage is done.
The assembler's code to match mnemonics is here.  It scans through the list of strings searching for a match, incrementing CX after each failure.   So when it finally does find a match, CX is the index of the matched mnemonic in the list.  This list is in the same order as the OPTAB table, which contains pointers to the functions that parse the instruction's operands.
When you overwrote the null byte following JCXZ, you effectively merged JCXZ and JNB into one mnemonic, and now the list is out of sync with OPTAB.  So when we are trying to parse the third instruction MOV, which is later in the list than JCXZ and JNB, we only increment CX once when we pass them.  This means that when we do reach MOV in the list, CX has been incremented one time too few.  So when we use that value (now in BX) as an index into OPTAB, it points not to the proper entry for MOV, but to the preceding one.  Which is, you guessed it, MOVSW (or MOVW as the comment puts it).
So we assemble the opcode for MOVSW, which is what you see in the dump.  But MOVSW takes no operands, so the rest of the line AX, 2200 is not parsed as an operand, but as a new instruction.  Since AX isn't a valid instruction mnemonic, we get an error.

That’s it! Thank you so much for clarifying these details! When I wrote the instructions to the 0:200 memory address (still using debug.exe in my MS-DOS VM), it worked perfectly. I chose this address because I learned that it is typically left blank and unused in MS-DOS. Besides, before inserting instructions into the memory, I now make sure it is filled with zeros, allowing me to confidently overwrite the bytes.

Nate and @RioskyLiao: rcgldr commented under the question that you can a 100 which will default to an available segment.  (org 0x100 is the offset within some segment where a .com executable is loaded and executes from, so that seems like a good choice if you want to write the machine code to a file to run outside a debugger).  Nate's answer suggests using a with no address; that might be equivalent or similar.

@RioskyLiao: Checking for zeros isn't really the right test; it's conceivable that zeroed memory is someone else's data that just happens to be zero at the moment.  Conversely, memory that is allocated for your use will not necessarily be zeroed; it may have contents left over from some previous program.  (On modern OSes that would be a privacy leak, but DOS isn't a modern OS and doesn't care.)

@PeterCordes a 100, which I originally suggested, uses the current cs by default. Just after starting Debug without an executable to load, a plain a and a 100 are the same as asmadd is initialised to cs:100h initially. The default empty debuggee process looks like the initial condition of a flat .COM format executable having been loaded. The first 256 bytes at cs:0 contain a Process Segment Prefix and you'd better not overwrite them.
